# I am having trouble with computing area of rose curve.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, area

I computed the area of rose curve, $r = \cos (3\theta)$ by computing one petal first and then multiply it by $3$. then I evaluated the same integral again over the interval $[0,2 \pi]$. Why aren't both results the same?

Comment: What is the period of the curve? Trace out how long it takes to return to the same $xy$ point.

Comment: Please give more details of your calculation.  What you've written only tells the Reader that you expected to get "both results the same", but didn't, without showing the actual integrals calculated.  One or both could be "wrong" but a common source of discrepancy is that one integral may "count" some area as a negative, thereby offsetting some "positive" area.  I can't tell if this applies from the little you shared.

Comment: Mathematical notation [can be used on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) with a little bit of a learning curve.

Comment: What were the evaluated values in the two cases?

Answer (score 0):

Because the period of the function $r=\cos(3\theta)$ is $\pi$. This should be the upper bound of your integral.

Comment: That is incorrect. The period of this polar curve is $\pi$. Trace out the curve or do the area integral to see which one matches.

Comment: whoops silly mistake thank you

Comment: i get it now. thank you.